# How to write unordered list in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, html-lists

I am trying to create and unordered list for an array of errors I am printing from my console. I am using vue.js and am struggling to understand how to write this. My relevant code is below.

Script for printing errors:

```
export default {

    name: 'post',

    data () {

        return {

            validationErrors: []

        }

    },

    methods: {

        getPost () {

            //irrelevant code

            .then(({data}) => {        

                this.validationErrors = data.validationErrors     

            })

        },

        postUpdate () {

            //more irrelevant code

            .catch(error => {

                console.log(error);

                this.validationErrors = error.response.data.validationErrors;
            })

        } 

    }

}
```

How I am displaying the errors:

```
<p v-show="(this.validationErrors || '').length > 0">{{this.validationErrors != null && validationErrors.length > 0 ? validationErrors[0].msg : ""}}</p>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what result you want, but it's easier to reason about if you make sure `validationError` is always an array - even if empty- and not null. Then you don't have to check for length or if it's null, you can simply do this

```
<p v-for="error in validationErrors" :key="error.msg">
    {{ error.msg }}
</p>
```

If there are no errors, than nothing renders.